# Generics and the visitor pattern

Tags: java, generics, visitor-pattern

I am having a problem with the Visitor pattern and generics. I have some abstract class whose children are to be visited. Look at this code:

```
public abstract class Element extends SomeSuperClass {
    public void accept(Visitor<? extends Element> v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public interface Visitor<T extends SomeSuperClass> {
    void visit(T element);
}
```

So the idea is: I have some class hierarchy (e.g. `Element` is a subclass of `SomeSuperClass`).
I have got some generic `Visitor` interface to visit this hierarchy. Now in the middle of this hierarchy is the `Element` class, which is abstract and has it's own subclasses.

Now I want `Element` to accept all visitors of its subclasses, which is why I put this line:

```
public void accept(Visitor<? extends Element> v)
```

But now I am receiving error:

> The method visit (`capture#1-of ? extends Element`) in the type `Visitor<capture#1-of ? extends Element>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Element`).

I understand that `? extends Element` is not `Element`. My question is: Can I express my idea in a different way? Or I have just missed the idea of generics in this case?

Comment: Is this a compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: @RomanC This is most definitely a compile-time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `T` in `<T extends SomeSuperClass>` can be a type completely unrelated to `Element` and the compiler must ensure for the general case that `visit(T t)` will work for every possible `T`.

The code you have calls `Visitor.visit(Element e)`, but the visitor in question could be `Visitor<SubElement>`. That wouldn't make sense.

I think that the requirement "`Element` must accept all visitors of its subclasses" doesn't make sense: the visitor must at least be able to visit `Element` **and all its subclasses**. That would be a `Visitor<Element>`.

The construct `accept(Visitor<? extends Element> v)` means that `v` can be any such `Visitor<T>` that `T extends Element`. It **does not** mean that the visitor itself will be of the type `Visitor<? extends Element>`. In fact, no such thing even exists in Java. Every Visitor will have a specific type parameter associated with it, not a wildcard.

Comment: But that`s why I wrote method `public void accept(Visitor<? extends Element> v)` to be sure that visitor could not be `Visitor<SubElement>`. Anyway I got the idea that I wanted to be too much flexible. Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the semantics, then. `accept(Visitor<? extends ELement>)` is exactly the construct that **allows** `Visitor<SubElement>`. It allows any `Visitor<T>` such that `T extends Element`.

Comment: Yeah righ now I got it, finally.

Comment: Hi @MarkoTopolnik, if you have a few minutes, could you please take a look at my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869706/can-the-visitor-pattern-to-be-used-to-perform-generic-double-dispatch/31874400. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that what you're trying to do makes much sense. Making `Visitor` generic is useless: the `accept()` method must take a specific visitor interface as argument, so that subclasses of `Element` may be able to call specific overloads of `visit()`.

```
interface Visitor {
  void visit(Element e);
  void visit(SubElement e);
}

class Element {
  public void accept(Visitor v) {
    v.visit(this);
  }
}

class SubElement { 
  public void accept(Visitor v) {
    v.visit(this);
  }
}

class ElementVisitor implements Visitor {
  public void visit(Element e) {}
  public void visit(SubElement e) {}
}
```

Note that the `Visitor` interface must be aware of all the classes in the `Element` hyerarchy that need a custom `visit()` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

That cannot work - the visitors of `? extends Element` may need to be able to access data (attributes / methods, ...) that `Element` doesn't have or know about.

You can't get a visitor that's supposed to visit objects that extends `Element` to necessarily be able to visit something that's a straight `Element` or even another, completely separate, subclass of `Element`.

Answer (score 2):

The most general way to write it would be:

```
public void accept(Visitor<? super Element> v) {
    v.visit(this);
}
```

That way, even a `Visitor<Object>` would work (why shouldn't it).

Remember PECS (producer `extends`, consumer `super`). The visitor is a consumer, so it should be `super`.