# Can the Visitor Pattern to be used to perform generic double dispatch?

Tags: java, generics

If you search for generic versions of Visitor Pattern, you find things like this:

```
public abstract class Element {
    public void accept(Visitor<? extends Element> v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public interface Visitor<T extends Element> {
    void visit(T element);
}
```

(adapted from [Generics and the visitor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109698/generics-and-the-visitor-pattern)).

However, this seems prohibit double dispatch, since the "second" dispatch—the one that depends on method overloading—is not possible with the generic method parameter. So, does using generics with the Visitor Pattern prohibit double dispatch?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't destroy it, just makes it ugly. Instead of having:

```
 class MyVisitor implement Visitor<Element>{

   void visit(ElementA ea) {..}

   void visit(ElementB eB) {..}

}
```

you end up having to add the dispatching yourself with `instanceof` :

```
class MyVisitor implement Visitor<Element>{

   void visit(Element e) { 

       if(e instanceof ElementA) {

             //dispatch to the method
             visit((ElementA) e); 

       else( e instanceof ElementB) {
            //or do the logic right here ..
      }

   }

   void visit(ElementA ea) {..}

}
```

**Edit**
You can have such a solution:

```
class ElementVisitor {

 void visit(ElementA ea)

 void visit(ElementB eb)
```

}

If now the client does like:

```
 class ElementA {

   void accept(ElementVisitor ev) { 
       ev.accept(this); // this call will be dispatched to visit(ElementA)
  }
```

}

then the visit is dispatched to the right method. The problem with this approach is that its not generic, you have to write a different `Visitor` interface for each family of types to be visited. The other way you just have one `Visitor` interface for all types.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a shame though. It's one thing that it's ugly, but it's lame because it loses its compile safety :(

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean exactly? If you check with `instanceof` then the cast is safe. If you 're familiar with `scala`s pattern matching mechanism , (which makes for nicer version of this solution) it also gets compiled to `instanceof` checks and casts.

Comment: I'm familiar with pattern matching but didn't know it gets compiled into instanceof checks. Cool! I meant, though, compile time safety you get by specifying an interface of overloaded visit methods that must be implemented by a visitor for the compile to happen. I guess you could do the same just with visit* methods that are called in the instanceof checks.

Comment: Yes, I show that case on my code sample with the `visit( ElementA ea)`. You still have to cast it to an `ElementA` though

Comment: That's right, but you could add `ElementC`, then add `visit(ElementC ec)` to the interface and implement that method in the class, but then forgot to add it to the generic dispatcher method `visit(Element e)`, which would lead to successful compilation but practical runtime failure.

Comment: Hmm, it depends. If `visit(ElementC ec)` is part of the interface, and is called by an `ElementC` by doing `visitor.visit(this)`, then the its dispatched directly to `visit(ElementC ec)`, not to `visit(Element e)`. Since the compiler knows `this` is an instance of `ElementC`, then it make the call to the most exact method.  I'll add something to the answer.